# which one should i use and why: {} vs = in c++

Tags: c++

I was watching MVA's(Microsoft Visual Academy's) tutorials and I came across these two operators i.e. `{}` and `=` to pass in the value to variables. I have done C programming so I am pretty much aware of the assignment operator `=`. But `{}` is not in any programming language I've worked on so far.

Kate is teaching the C++ course so she told that `{}` is used for copying.

But I was using the operator `{}` in the class below and it shows some error when I try to do this:

```
this->_width{new_width};
```

whereas below one works:

```
this->_width = new_width;
```

Why so? I am also using `{}` to pass values in constructor but then they work perfectly. Only Problem is with member functions.

```
class Rectangle
{

public:
     void resize(int new_height, int new_width)  { this->_width{new_width} ; this->_height{new_height} };        //member function
     
     Rectangle(): _width{} , height{} {}   //constructor

private:
     int _width; 
     int _height; 

};
```

Comment: `{}` isn't an [operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Your constructor is using a member initialization list to *construct* its members. Your member function *code* should be *assigning to* members.  This isn't Lisp. Sometimes you have to reach for the `'='` key.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`{}` can be used to initialise variables in C++11 in the same way that they are used to initialise arrays and structures in C.

This has been introduced primarily to provide consistency in language syntax (initialising with `{}` will work in all contexts, whereas initialising using the assignment operator or `()` will work in specific contexts.

There is a further advantage to list initialisation in that it prevents *narrowing* - i.e. it prevents you from providing an integer when a double is required, or a short when an integer is required. In this way it can help to reduce bugs.

Note that `{}` cannot be used to pass values to a function - only to construct new objects.

[This page is also worth reading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

Comment: `{}` can be used to pass a value to a function.  `void f(int); f({3});` works, as does far more complex cases.  Use of `{}` in function arguments is not only allowed, it is awesome.

Comment: @Yakk It might refer to `f{3}`

Comment: @dyp probably, but the existence of a valid reading when you say 'cannot', especially when there are awesome uses, means clarification is needed.

Comment: @Yakk `f({3})` works because the round brackets are introducing an integer that has been initialised by the curly braces. The curly braces are initialising, not passing a value to a function. The assertion holds, as it is in agreement with the c++ standard.

Comment: --1 then: Your assertion is poorly worded and misleading.

Comment: @Yakk are you able to provide better wording? I'm happy to incorporate it into the answer if it provides a better explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Using `{}` is called **uniform initialization** in this context. It was introduced mainly for two reasons.

First, as the name indicates, initialization is uniform, that is it looks and works the same for single objects, arrays, containers that accept initializer lists, etc.

Second, and equally important, it is impossible to get a [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) using curly braces, which is quite possible unintentionally otherwise:

```
A a(); // What does this do? What was probably intended?
B b{}; // And what does this do?
```

Also, as a bonus (kudos to @Richard Hodges), you avoid narrowing conversions using uniform initialization.

To literally answer the question "which one should I use?", you should preferrably use `{}` as it has only advantages, and no disadvantages (plus, Bjarne Stroustrup recommends using it).

Comment: But watch out for constructors that have `std::initializer_list` overrides, such as `std::string s{10, 'a'}` - this is very different from `std::string s(10, 'a')`!  I'm not actually sure how one invokes this constructor without using `()` - anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

Non-static data members may be initialized in one of two ways:
1) In the member initializer list of the constructor.

```
struct S {
    int n;
    std::string s;
    S() : n(7) // direct-initializes n, default-initializes s
    { }
};
```

2) Through a brace-or-equal initializer, which is simply an initializer included in the member declaration, which is used if the member is omitted in the member initializer list

```
struct S {
    int n = 7;
    std::string s{'a', 'b', 'c'};
    S() // copy-initializes n, list-initializes s
    { }
};
```

You may use brace initializers in the member declaration.

Also, from the standard, N4296, § 9.2, paragraph 4:

> A brace-or-equal-initializer shall appear only in the declaration of
>   a data member.

Comment: Simple and useful.